Convergence of Gauss-Seidel in sup-norm
I have a matrix symmetric $A \in M_{n,n}(\mathbb{R})$ with $\rho(A) < 1$, and an arbitrary vector $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$ with $\|x\|_\infty < 1$. Assume further that $\rho(A) \approx 1 - n^{-2}$. It is clear that $\|A^k x\|_2 \to 0$, and, if I denote by $k(\epsilon)$ the smallest $k$ such that $\|A^kx\|_2 \leq \epsilon$, then $k(\epsilon) = O(n^2)$.
I was thinking if we can say anything about convergence in sup-norm, i.e. can we get any bounds on $l(\epsilon)$; the least $l$ such that $\|A^l x\|_\infty \leq \epsilon$?
My claim is that we can guarantee $O(n^{5/2})$, by the following reasoning(it is just a a rough sketch)
Let $\alpha_1 \geq \cdots \geq \alpha_n$ be the eigenvalues of $A$ with corresponding eigenvectors $v_1, \ldots, v_n$. Then, on the long term all components of $A^nx$ corresponding to eigenvectors other that $v_1$ can be ignored (they vanish quicker). Note that, since $A$ symmetric, the $v_i$ are orthogonal, so they for a basis. Consider the decomposition of $x$ using the $v_i$ as $x = \sum_i \lambda_i v_i$. Then:
$$\sum_i \lambda_i ^2 \|v_i\|^2 = \|x\|_2^2 \leq n \cdot \|x\|_\infty^2$$
from which $|\lambda_1| \leq \frac{\sqrt{n} \|x\|_\infty}{\|v_1\|}\leq \frac{\sqrt{n} }{\|v_1\|}$. Finally, we need
$$\alpha_1^n |\lambda_1| \cdot \|v_1\|_\infty \leq \epsilon$$
and after using the bound on $|\lambda_1|$ we get the result.
My questions are: is this reasoning correct, and can we obtain anything better?

I think it is correct. Essentially it is the leading eigenvalue of the discretised laplacian matrix -- but also I believe it doesn't really matter, as the convergence should be slowed down by the same rate?

Oh, sorry yes its $n^{-2}$, skimmed over the typo.

Looking at this problem again, it might not even make any sense, as $|x|_\infty \leq |x|_2$, so the convergence can't be slower.
